# When is distance covariance less appropriate than linear covariance?

Tags: correlation, covariance, distance-covariance

I've just been introduced (vaguely) to [brownian/distance covariance/correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_covariance). It seems particularly useful in many non-linear situations, when testing for dependence. But it doesn't seem to be used very often, even though covariance/correlation are often used for non-linear/chaotic data.

That has me thinking that there might be some drawbacks to distance covariance. So what are they, and why doesn't everyone just always use distance covariance?

Comment: For reference, I created a [distance correlation version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation) of the [correlation graph on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation)

Comment: I read that you were using dcov to compare non linear time series and combine them with weight..I was wondering if what you did is using a weighted distance covariance..meaning that you gave different weights to your data using a weight vector to calculate the distance correlation? I'm trying to do that but I'm not sure if introducing a weight vector into the distance correlation formulas is the right way to go.

Comment: No, sorry @user3757561, I was just trying distance correlation as a replacement for correlation, and then creating weights based on that. But I didn't end up using it anyway...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*I have tried to collect a few remarks on distance covariance based on my impressions from reading the references listed below. However, I do not consider myself an
expert on this topic. Comments, corrections, suggestions, etc. are welcome.*

*The remarks are (strongly) biased towards
potential drawbacks, as requested in the original question*.

As I see it, the potential drawbacks are as follows:

1. **The methodology is new**. My guess is that this is the single
    biggest factor regarding lack of popularity at this time. The
    papers outlining distance covariance start in the mid 2000s and
    progress up to present day. The paper cited above is the one that
    received the most attention (hype?) and it is less than three years
    old. In contrast, the theory and results on correlation and
    correlation-like measures have over a century of work already
    behind them.
2. **The basic concepts are more challenging**. Pearson's
    product-moment correlation, at an operational level, can be
    explained to college freshman without a calculus background
    pretty readily. A simple "algorithmic" viewpoint can be laid
    out and the geometric intuition is easy to describe. In contrast, in the case of distance covariance, even the notion of sums of products of pairwise Euclidean
    distances is quite a bit more difficult and the notion of
    covariance with respect to a stochastic process goes far beyond
    what could reasonably be explained to such an audience.
3. **It is computationally more demanding**. The basic algorithm for
    computing the test statistic is $O(n^2)$ in the sample size as
    opposed to $O(n)$ for standard correlation metrics. For small
    sample sizes this is not a big deal, but for larger ones it
    becomes more important.
4. **The test statistic is not distribution free, even
    asymptotically**. One might hope that for a test statistic that is
    consistent against all alternatives, that the
    distribution—at least asymptotically—might be
    independent of the underlying distributions of $X$ and $Y$ under
    the null hypothesis. This is not the case for distance covariance 
    as the distribution under the null depends on the underlying
    distribution of $X$ and $Y$ even as the sample size tends to
    infinity. It *is* true that the distributions are uniformly
    bounded by a $\chi^2_1$ distribution, which allows for the
    calculation of a *conservative* critical value.
5. **The distance correlation is a one-to-one transform of $|\rho|$ in
    the bivariate normal case**. This is not really a drawback, and
    might even be viewed as a strength. But, if one accepts a
    bivariate normal approximation to the data, which can be quite
    common in practice, then little, if anything, is gained from
    using distance correlation in place of standard procedures.
6. **Unknown power properties**. Being consistent against all
    alternatives essentially guarantees that distance covariance must
    have very low power against some alternatives. In many cases, one
    is willing to give up generality in order to gain additional
    power against particular alternatives of interest. The original
    papers show some examples in which they claim high power relative
    to standard correlation metrics, but I believe that, going back
    to (1.) above, its behavior against alternatives is not yet well
    understood.

To reiterate, this answer probably comes across quite negative. But,
that is not the intent. There are some very beautiful and interesting
ideas related to distance covariance and the relative novelty of it
also opens up research avenues for understanding it more fully.

**References**:

1. G. J. Szekely and M. L. Rizzo (2009), [Brownian distance
   covariance](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1267453933), *Ann. Appl. Statist.*, vol. 3, no. 4, 1236–1265.
2. G. J. Szekely, M. L. Rizzo and N. K. Bakirov (2007), [Measuring and
   testing independence by correlation of distances](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1201012979), *Ann. Statist.*,
   vol. 35, 2769–2794.
3. R. Lyons (2012), [Distance covariance in metric spaces](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/pdf/dcov.pdf),
   *Ann. Probab.* (to appear).

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Some of it is a bit over my head, but I think I'll be able to remedy that myself :)

Comment: See also Summary and discussion of: “Brownian Distance Covariance”
Statistics Journal Club, 36-825 Benjamin Cowley and Giuseppe Vinci
October 27, 2014 http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/journalclub/dcov.pdf

Comment: When both random variables are univariate the distance correlation can be computed in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ time, see https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.2015.1054435 for example.

Answer (score 3):

I could well be missing something, but just having a quantification of the nonlinear dependence between two variables doesn't seem to have much of a payoff.  It won't tell you the shape of the relationship.  It won't give you any means to predict one variable from the other.  By analogy, when doing exploratory data analysis one sometimes uses a loess curve (locally weighted scatterplot smoother) as a first step towards seeing whether the data are best modeled with a straight line, a quadratic, a cubic, etc.  But the loess in and of itself is not a very useful predictive tool.  It's just a first approximation on the way to finding a workable equation to describe a bivariate shape.  That equation, unlike the loess (or the distance covariance result), can form the basis of a confirmatory model.

Comment: For my purposes, it does have a payoff. I'm not using dcov() for predicting anything, rather, comparing multiple non-linear time-series in an ensemble, and combining them with weights based on their dependence. In this situation, dcov() has potentially large benefits.

Comment: @naught101 Can you put in some m ore info.- when you say -'combine'? This sounds interesting to me in terms of weighting based on nonlinear dependence. Do you mean- categorizing the time series into groups? Also-what do high and low weights emphasize in this scenario?

Comment: @PraneethVepakomma: check out my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562/when-to-use-multiple-models-for-prediction/25127#25127

Comment: Also, if you know the general form of dependence (e.g., polynomial equation), then you may quantify the strength of the dependence using the coefficient of determination, see, e.g., [Computing Adjusted R2 for Polynomial Regressions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html#bswinlz)